# How to ensure my regular expression does not match too much

Tags: tcl

A file has few words with numbers in the begining of them. i want to extract a particular no line.when given 1, it extracts line 1 also with 11, 21

FILE.txt has contents:

```
1.sample
lines of
2.sentences
present in
...
...
10.the 
11.file
```

when Executed `pro 1 file.txt`
gives results from line 1,10 and also from line 11 
as these three results have 1 in their string. i.e

Output of the script:

```
1.sample
10.the 
11.file
```

Expected output: the output which i am expecting 
is only line 1 contents and not the line 10 or line 11 contents.
i.e

Expected output:

```
1.sample
```

My current code:

```
proc pro { pattern args} {

   set file [open $args r]
   set lnum 0
   set occ 0 
   while {[gets $file line] >=0} {
      incr lnum
      if {[regexp $pattern $line]} {
          incr occ
          puts "The pattern is present in line: $lnum" 
          puts "$line"
      } else {
         puts "not found"
      }
   }
   puts "total number of occurencese : $occ"
   close $file
}
```

the program is working fine but the thing is i am retrieving lines that i dont want to along with the expected line. As the number (1) which i want to retrieve is present in the other strings such as 11, 21, 14 etc these lines are also getting printed.

kindly tolerate my unclear way of explaining the question.

Comment: It's not very clear as to what you are trying to achieve here.  What errors/problems do you have with the code you have posted? Can you add a short sample input file and the output you expect from the procedure to make the requirements clearer?

Comment: Are you really using a pattern or are you looking for a literal at the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem using word boundaries as suggested by glen but you can also consider the following things:

If after every line number there is a `.` then you can use it as delimiter in regular expression

```
regexp "^$lineNo\\." $a
```

I would also suggest to use `^` (match at the beginning of line) so that even if number is present in the line elsewhere it would not get counted.

tcl word boundaries are well explained at http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: `.` matches anything in a regexp.  Escape it as `\.` to match a literal dot.

Comment: I had used \. but i think to appear it in the post we have to use \\ . Edited the post. Thanks

Comment: thank you everybody for helping me out with this confusion. The answer suggested by "Donal" works absolutely fine when merged with the answer of "Evil otto" ---------regexp "^$lineno\." $a----------

Comment: thank you everybody for helping me out with this confusion. The answer suggested by "Donal" works absolutely fine. 
regexp "^$lineno\\." $a

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure your pattern matches only between word boundaries:

```
if {[regexp "\\m$pattern\\M" $line]} { ...
```

See the documentation for [regular expression syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M72).

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking to do is as constrained as what you're describing, why not just use something like

```
if { [string range $line 0 [string length $pattern]] eq "${pattern}." } {
    ...
}
```

Comment: or, `string match "$pattern.*" $line`

Comment: @otto - That'll work too... I tend to avoid pattern matchers if I don't need them for speed, but string match might be clearer.